# How to change the view for a rendered product?

Tags: theming, commerce

I'm learning Drupal Commerce with a Commerce Kickstart installation. I understood in part the way products are displayed, with variation types and content types.

Have made some changes like visible/hidden product fields, and change the order product fields are displayed.

I would like to modify the position of the image to be on the left side and title, description and *Add to cart* button should stay on the right side.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two high level options: 1) create page templates for your product displays in the theme layer that include the markup your CSS needs to position things or 2) use a module like Panels that lets you build page layouts from within the Drupal admin UI itself. (I'm assuming this is Drupal 7, but if you are on Drupal 8, you should give the core Layout Builder module a try vs. Panels.)

Comment: Thank you, I've finally managed how to arrange the product fields as I want. I used Layout Builder from UI.